# Bootstrap Borderless Table Still Has Border?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5, razor-pages

Pretty new to Boostrap and cannot figure out what may be triggering this line on my Create view and how to eliminate it.

[image: Mystery Bootstrap Line]

Here is a portion of my view pertinent to that area:

```
 <h3 class="text-primary pl-3">Client Demographic Information</h3>
        <table class="table table-bordeless" style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 30%">
                    <div class="form-group, mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Incident.CaseType"></label>
                        <br />
                        @foreach (var item in Html.GetEnumSelectList<CaseType>())
                        {
                            <input type="radio" asp-for="Incident.CaseType" value="@item.Text"/>@item.Text
                        }
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 30%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Incident.PIFirstName"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Incident.PIFirstName" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Incident.PIFirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 10%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Incident.PIMiddleInitial"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Incident.PIMiddleInitial" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Incident.PIMiddleInitial" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td style="width: 30%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Incident.PILastName"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Incident.PILastName" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Incident.PILastName" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table class="table table-bordeless" style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="width: 40%">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label asp-for="Incident.PIAddressCity"></label>
                        <select asp-for="Incident.PIAddressCity" id="Select1" class="form-select" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.DisplayCityData.OrderBy(x => x.CityName),"CityName", "CityName"))"><option value="" selected disabled>---Select Residence City---</option></select>
                    </div>
                </td>
```

Hoping someone can assist. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class name has typo:

```
table class="table table-bordeless"
```

change with:

```
table class="table table-borderless"
```

Comment: I have been staring at that for hours and never saw that! Thank you so much!!! Another set of eyes was what I needed.